# How do I know one table's primary key field value is used in any another related tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do I know one table's primary key field value (eg ID) is used in any another related tables in MySQL?

Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to know if other tables have defined `FOREIGN KEY` constraints against it, or if a specific value is used in possibly related tables?

Comment: I mean a specific value is used or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the structure of your database. Then you can do something like

```
select * from your_table where id in 
(
    select id from ref_table1
    union
    select id from ref_table2
    union
    select id from ref_table3
)
```

Comment: not necessary, if you have indexes, if you add a ORDER BY at the end of each select that will make it slow

Comment: but if i have 50 related tables for a primary key tables , i need to write 50 queries in there . Is that a good way ?

Comment: No that is not a good way. Maybe you should think about adding a column to the table with your primary key that indicates if it is referenced somewhere. You could set that field when inserting in a foreign key table. With a trigger for instance.